# How to change grid size in gridview dynamically android?

Tags: android, android-layout

My problem lies with that the Image in the gridview is say 200x500, but each grid area is 500x500 (These are examples not accurate).  I have a 2x4 grid that is static and doesn't change.  I can change the horizontal spacing by setting android:verticalspacing but that causes all sorts of issues on different sized screen.  Preferably I would like to just shrink each grid to match the image and have it dynamic across screen sizes.  Below is my Gridview adapter and layout xml

```
public class MainAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.install, R.drawable.wipe,
            R.drawable.backup, R.drawable.restore,
            R.drawable.mount, R.drawable.settings,
            R.drawable.advanced, R.drawable.reboot
    };

    // Constructor
    public MainAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId=""
    />
        </LinearLayout>


    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_view" >  

    </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: for that you can use simple values in values folder.

Comment: What would the value be?

Comment: you can set android:numColumns="auto_fit" and this will dynamically set in all resolution

Comment: It needs to be 2x4.  Cant really move from that.